What is the arity of a degenerate Boolean function? Or rather: Are there good names for the two possible answers?
For Boolean functions the term “arity” is somewhat ambiguous.
I would say, that there are three different meanings, two of which are important.

small: $A \land C$ has arity 2, because input $B$ is fictitious.

big: $A \land C$ has arity 3, because the truth table requires length 8.

big and sloppy: $A \land C$ has arity 3 or bigger


The sloppy meaning usually appears like this: The number of $n$-ary functions is $2 ^ {2 ^ n}$.
Whe know what it means, that there are 16 binary functions.
But we also know, that the tautology is one of them,
and on its own we would not call it a binary function.
What I really care about is the arity of a specific function.
For non-degenerate functions there is no ambiguity, e.g. $A \land (B \lor C)$ is a 3-ary function.
But for $A \land C$ both 2 and 3 are relevant values.
My question is how to call them.
If someone has already defined reasonable terms, I would be glad to use them.
But I would also be interested in suggestions, that would not clash with existing conventions.
Edits:
I should have written “Boolean expression” instead of “function”.
It is implied, that the expression represents a function.
Sources for the term “degenerate Boolean function”:

Sloane's A000371: Number of nondegenerate Boolean functions of n variables.
(E.g. there are 10 binary and 218 ternary non-degenerate BF.)
On the Degree of BF as Polynomials over Zm:
A Boolean function is called non-degenerate if it depends on all its n variables.


As a function, maybe include what its domain is? Then the arity would be clearer.

There is as much ambiguity in $A \wedge (B \vee C)$ as in $A \wedge C$. For example, one can have a function $f(x,y,z,u,v)=x\wedge(y\vee z)$.

An expression alone doesn't define a function - you need to specify the domain, which determines the arity. E.g. a binary function is a function that takes two inputs; it doesn't matter what values it produces.

For me the context is the infinite set of all Boolean functions $f(A, B, C, D, E, ...)$. My definition of degenerate is like in the integer sequence quoted above. $A \land (B \lor C)$ is among the 218 truly 3-ary functions (but $A \land C$ is not). $A \lor \neg B$ is among the 10 truly 2-ary functions (but $\neg B$ ist not).

I have only the expression. So the domain is what it needs to be do deal with it. So I see $A \land C$ as a 3-ary function $f(A, B, C)$, and $\neg D$ as a 4-ary function $f(A, B, C, D)$. What I am looking for is a word to express, that the former uses only two, and the latter uses only 1 input.

I chose to (ab)use the synonyms of “arity” for this purpose:

Valency is the number of arguments actually used.
(It is the number of circles in an Euler diagram.)
$A \land C$ has valency 2.

Adicity follows from the biggest argument.
($2 ^ {adicity}$ is the minimum length required for the truth table.)
$A \land C$ has adicity 3.

Arity is only used, when the expression is represented by a function.
$A \land C$ requires arity 3 or bigger.


The relationship is $valency \le adicity \le arity$.

This may require a little context.
For some people is may sound weird,
that $A \land C$ should have different properties than $A \land B$.
But $A$ and $C$ are not just meaningless variable names.
When there is a $C$, there is an implied $B$.
For me each of these letters denotes a specific unary Boolean function with a periodic truth table:
$A$ = 01010101...
$B$ = 00110011...
$C$ = 00001111...
So $A \land C$ = 00000101..., while $A \land B$ = 0001... = 00010001...
The period length of $A \land C$ is 8.
So a finite truth table must have at least length 8.
That is why I say, that $A \land C$ requires arity 3 or bigger.
BTW, these periodic truth tables can be interpreted as fractions between 0 and 1:
$x_0 = \frac{1}{3}$,    
$x_1 = \frac{1}{5}$,    
$x_2 = \frac{1}{17}$,    
$x_3 = \frac{1}{257}$          
$x_n = \frac{1}{2^{2^n} + 1}$
 
If this all sounds like a strange way to talk about Boolean functions, it may be, because I come from programming, and not from mathematics.
I think that these examples may be helpful to get an idea of what I am doing. (Especially the ones called darimi and basori.)

I would have thought that $A\land C$ requires arity 2 or bigger. After all, $\land$ is a binary operator.

These are not just random variable names. I matters, that the biggest letter in the expression is $C$. The reason I need these three different words is exactly to avoid this confusion. With the words I have chosen now, $\neg D$ has valency 1 and adicity 4. The latter means, that it requires arity 4 or bigger. I have expanded my answer to explain it.
